# Write/ read Plist in swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift2, plist

Trying to save addObject to Array inside `plist` but don't know how to do it...

the structure of the Plist is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Location</key>
    <array>
        <string>test</string>
        <string>test2</string>
    </array>
    <key>UserID</key>
    <array>
        <string>use1</string>
        <string>user2</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

this is what I use:

read plist from Documents directory works fine....
in my viewDidLoad

```
 guard
            let fileURL =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyPlist.plist")
            else { fatalError("Unable to get file") }

        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
        locationArray = dict?.objectForKey("Location") as! NSMutableArray
        userIDArray = dict?.objectForKey("UserID") as! NSMutableArray
```

in my save func:

```
 guard
        let fileURL =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyPlist.plist")
        else { fatalError("Unable to get file") }

    let dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfURL: fileURL)

    dict?.setObject(userDefaultLocationTextField.text!, forKey: "Location")
    dict?.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true)
```

but it seems that nothing is written in my plist...

Thanks.

Comment: Is the dictionary being successfully updated in-memory (use the debugger to find out)?  This will tell you where the issue is (updating in memory or writing to file).  I am no expert with Swift but that `as! NSMutableArray` looks wrong...

Comment: i don't think so. Array has only one object after i save the new value

Comment: You don't appear to want to solve this issue.

Comment: what? what do you mean? why wouldn't I want to solve this issue?

Comment: You use the word "think" which I interpret as "I don't know and don't want to find out".

Comment: no no. I said I don't think so because in my log it is not updated....

Comment: You cannot cast an immutable to a mutable Foundation type.

Comment: but I use NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray, why are they immutable?

Comment: It's recommended to use always Swift native collection types. The lines containing `as! NSMutableArray` don't result mutable types. You need `mutableCopy` or `NSMutableArray(array:..)`

Comment: ok. but when i read the file is fine (when using as! MutableArray) my issue is "updating" the entries in which case I do not use that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than the simple `NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: fileURL)` I recommend to use the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class.

Due to Swift's value type semantics you need to update the root dictionary after changing one of the arrays, for example

```
guard
  let fileURL =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyPlist.plist"),
  fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
  else { fatalError("Unable to get file") }

do {
  var dict = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(fileData, options: .MutableContainersAndLeaves, format: nil) as! [String:AnyObject]

  var locationArray = dict["Location"] as! [String]
  locationArray.append(userDefaultLocationTextField.text!)
  dict["Location"] = locationArray // this line is crucial to update the enclosing dictionary

  let outputData = try NSPropertyListSerialization.dataWithPropertyList(dict, format: NSPropertyListFormat.XMLFormat_v1_0, options: 0)
  try outputData.writeToURL(fileURL, options: .AtomicWrite)
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and suggestion. Is my solution "unsafe" or is this the "proper" way to do it?

Comment: Your solution is supposed to work, too, but `NSPropertyListSerialization` is the dedicated class to serialize property lists. Regarding your issue in the question the crucial information is to update the root dictionary. And using Swift's native types avoids the confusion what is reference and what is value type.

Comment: Consider also Core Data to store the arrays. Even for small data models it's more convenient than simple property lists.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working now for me:
Do you think that this is correct?

```
 guard
            let fileURL =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyPlist.plist")
            else { fatalError("Unable to get file") }

        let dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
        locationArray = dict?.objectForKey("Location") as! NSMutableArray
        locationArray.addObject(userDefaultLocationTextField.text!)


        dict?.setObject(locationArray, forKey: "Location")
        dict?.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true)
        print(dict)
```